# How to set Cookies enabled in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, cookies, puppeteer

I am currently having the problem (puppeteer) in a project that I think cookies are not activated. But I also don't know how to activate them if they are not already activated from the beginning.

Comment: can you clarify a bit how you mean this? what is your initial set up in puppeteer? what is the behavior that suggests "cookies are not activated"? you can use `page.cookies()` to get all the cookies on the current page so you can check for yourself if they are set or not.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried as a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every website nowaday has Captcha, so we can skip the auto-login part.
I'm new too, I got an idea from [here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/251459/how-to-login-in-puppeteer) for this.

Firstly check if there is saved cookies.json file, if not,  do the manually login, you click the submit button yourself and solve the captcha puzzle (in non-headless mode), the page should be redirected to destination page.

Once the destination page is loaded, save the cookies in to a Json file for next time.

Example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs =  require('fs');


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, //launch in non-headless mode so you can see graphics
    defaultViewport: null
});


  let [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  
  const getCookies = async (page) => {
    // Get page cookies
    const cookies = await page.cookies()

    // Save cookies to file
    fs.writeFile('./cookies.json', JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 4), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        return
    });
}


    const setCookies = async (page) => {
    // Get cookies from file as a string
    let cookiesString = fs.readFileSync('./cookies.json', 'utf8');

    // Parse string
    let cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString)

    // Set page cookies
    await page.setCookie.apply(page, cookies);
    return
}
  
  
  
  
  page.on('request', async (req) => {
    
    // If URL is already loaded in to system
    if (req.url() === 'https://example.com/LoggedUserCP') {
        console.log('logged in, get the cookies');
        await getCookies(page);
    // if it's being in login page, try to set existed cookie
    }  else if (req.url() === 'https://example.com/Login?next=LoggedUserCP') {
        await setCookies(page);
       console.log('set the saved cookies');
    }
    

    // otherwise go to login page and login yourself
    req.continue();
});
  
  
  await page.goto('https://example.com/Login?next=LoggedUserCP');
 


    


})();
```